# Distributed computing with or-tools

Tags: or-tools

I want to distribute the work of a cp solver algorithm (or other deterministic Algorithms) in a simple way instead of looking for ways to break apart each specific problem into smaller ones.

Is it possible to execute the cp solver with a given number of threads (E.g., 64) and then have 8 different solvers run the same problem with a specific subset of 8 branches?

In this way I could distribute the solving of the problem in a generic way and then just check choose the best result returned.

Comment: Can you clarify the task? `specific subset of 8 branches`? Sounds like a simple form of look-ahead. Of course you can launch multiple solvers (without them know about each other; no communication!) and you can also control their number of threads in use. But you are in control of feeding them your *subproblems* somehow (e.g. fixing something in each of those instances). The only open question i see here is about memory-ownership: in worst-case, you will need to build the model as many times as solvers are used. But maybe there is a model-copy available too.

Comment: The task is an assignment optimization task. And maybe I should just say specific subset of threads. Because when you start the solver with 64 threads it breaks the problem down into 64 branches to run. If it's a deterministic algorithm then it will always have the same outcome, which means you could split the threads to multiple computers and combine the result.  And thread count is part of the "deterministic" variables.

Comment: Memory efficiency is not a concern, only computational time is. The distributed computer network charges by time, not resource usage. So it doesnt matter if 8 computers use 8 GB of RAM each to solve the problem.

Comment: The cp-sat solver does not divide the search tree between threads. There are no good framework to do this in the context of sat solver. The only thing you can try is called 'embarassingly parallel search's from J. C. Régin.